# PhoneGap -- or something else? For iOS app utilizing Swipes and Pinches

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, web, gestures

My iOS app needs to utilize "swipes" gestures and "pinches". I'd rather not develop native iOS app myself, but use some tool like PhoneGap or anything like that. I want this to be pretty much a Web app, as much as possible, so I don'd deal with constant forever-taking updates thru App Store.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Don't PhoneGap apps have to be submitted through the App Store too?

Comment: @BoltClock - I think the OP was referring to the update process, not the initial submission.

Comment: updates need to go through the app store too. in general i think that phonegap is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, PhoneGap App updates still need to go through the approval process, unless all of the content they are displaying is served from a remote site. Then you may as well just create a mobile optimized website. As for PhoneGap being a bad idea. That is just poppycock. Many native devs feel that way. I suspect they feel undermined by something being so simple in comparison. Don't get me wrong, native development has its place, but for simple (and even some complex) applications that need be cross-platform, PhoneGap is awesome. I need to support 4 platforms, I can't support 4 native codebases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes PhoneGap can work with swipe. I just got done trying it with jQuery Mobile to answer this questions here: [How to swipe between several jquery mobile pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533772/how-to-swipe-between-several-jquery-mobile-pages/7535201#7535201)

As for Pinch. The Mobile Safari browser that works inside of PhoneGap supports it, so I suspect that you would be able to use it in the same context as you would in a normal mobile web application. Pinch to zoom, double tap to Zoom and center to a block element. I do not believe that PhoneGap or JQuery Mobile give you access to any pinch events to intercept and do your own thing with, like "pinch to make a noise" or something.