# Adding swipe gesture support to jQuery Cycle

Tags: jquery, swipe, gestures

I'm using jQuery Cycle to run a slideshow but would love to add the ability for mobile users to "swipe" to the next and/or previous slide. It would be as simple as changing the "Next" and "Previous" buttons to accept a swipe as well as a click. Any ideas?

Comment: See answer using this link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533772/how-to-swipe-between-several-jquery-mobile-pages][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533772/how-to-swipe-between-several-jquery-mobile-pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the buttons that need to accept swipe, they will still need to work on touch. The main images/content panels will need to work with swipe.

I believe this can be achieved easily using jQuery cycle + jQuery mobile, as discussed in [this forum post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/swipe-action-adn-the-cycle-plugin-speed-of-transition)

Comment: This gives me swipe control. Bad thing is it causes some problems with the slider. (i.e. making it 6 slides instead of 3 in the pager and causing the first slide to auto fire) but I'll hopefully get that worked out. Thanks danwellman!